# How do I send a message from a thread using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I want my discord users to be able to queue up some tasks. In this example it is just pinging websites, but I eventually want it to do other long running tasks. When I run my bot, I get the following error:

```
ping-bot.py:22: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'respond_to_channel' was never awaited
  respond_to_channel()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Here's the code:

```
import os, discord, subprocess, asyncio
from discord import app_commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
CHANNEL=os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID')
GUILD=os.getenv('GUILD_ID')

queue = []


def ping_test():
    global queue
    old_queue = queue.copy() 
    while True:
        if queue != old_queue and len(queue) > 0:
            old_queue = queue.copy()
            retcode = subprocess.call("ping " + "-c 5 " + old_queue[0][0], shell=True)
            queue.pop(0)
            if len(queue) > 0:
                respond_to_channel()
                print(f"Now working on {queue[0][0]}")
        sleep(1)

async def respond_to_channel():
    ping_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL)
    await ping_channel.send(f"Testing... Now working on {queue[0][0]}")

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False
        daemon = Thread(target=ping_test, daemon=True, name='Monitor')
        daemon.start()

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id = GUILD))
            self.synced = True

client = MyClient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name = "greet", description = "Greetings!", guild = discord.Object(id = GUILD))

async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello {name}! I was made with Discord.py!")
    print(f'Sent from {interaction.user}')
    
@tree.command(name = "ping-test", description = "Use my computer to ping websites", guild = discord.Object(id = GUILD))

async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, website: str):
    queue.append([website, interaction.user.id])
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello <@{interaction.user.id}>! You want me to ping {website}. There are currently {len(queue) - 1} jobs in front of you.", file=discord.File('test.png'))


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I've found some 'solutions' that do work for the ping test, but I am going to allow my discord users to use my computer for some computationally heavy tasks that can take 5+ minutes. These other solution I found break the bot if the task takes more than a few minutes.

For this reason, I decided to implement a thread that process items in a list that will tag the user in a channel when it is done.

Comment: You really probably don't want to mix threads with `async`...

Comment: Nothing ties them together so I think it should be fine, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wanted to use [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) as it handles everything for you and runs in the async loop so nothing breaks.

I changed the thread call to

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 1)
async def ping_test():
    global queue
    global being_worked 
    global client
    ping_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL)
    if len(queue) > 0:
        if queue[0] != being_worked[0]:
            being_worked = queue.copy()
            retcode = subprocess.call("ping " + "-c 5 " + being_worked[0][0], shell=True)
            queue.pop(0)
            await ping_channel.send(f"Done working on {being_worked[0][0]}")
            if len(queue) > 0:
                await ping_channel.send(f"Testing... Now working on {queue[0][0]}")
                print(f"Now working on {queue[0][0]}")
    return
```

So now the full code looks like this:

```
import os, discord, subprocess
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
CHANNEL=int(os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID'))
GUILD=os.getenv('GUILD_ID')

queue = []
being_worked = []

@tasks.loop(seconds = 1)
async def ping_test():
    global queue
    global being_worked 
    global client
    ping_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL)
    if len(queue) > 0:
        if queue != being_worked:
            being_worked = queue.copy()
            retcode = subprocess.call("ping " + "-c 15 " + being_worked[0][0], shell=True)
            queue.pop(0)
            await ping_channel.send(f"Done working on {being_worked[0][0]}")
            if len(queue) > 0:
                await ping_channel.send(f"Testing... Now working on {queue[0][0]}")
                print(f"Now working on {queue[0][0]}")
    return

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id = GUILD))
            self.synced = True
        await ping_test.start()
        

client = MyClient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name = "greet", description = "Greetings!", guild = discord.Object(id = GUILD))

async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello {name}! I was made with Discord.py!")
    print(f'Sent from {interaction.user}')
    
@tree.command(name = "ping-test", description = "Use my computer to ping websites", guild = discord.Object(id = GUILD))

async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, website: str):
    queue.append([website, interaction.user.id])
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello <@{interaction.user.id}>! You want me to ping {website}. There are currently {len(queue) - 1} jobs in front of you.", file=discord.File('test.png'))


                
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `await` in front of the function `respond_to_channel()` should fix the issue.

```
await respond_to_channel()
```

Comment: It doesn't I have tried that already.

SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function

Comment: That's happening because the function `ping_test()` is not an `async` function,

If you change `def ping_test()` to `async def ping_test()` this may fix the issue.

Comment: Correct. That's the problem I don't know how to fix. I've tried making an async def start_daemon function to start it, but it complains about that too.

Comment: What error does it give you when you do that?

Comment: ping-bot.py", line 61, in start_daemon
    await daemon.start()
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Did you put `async` infront of `def ping_test()`?

Comment: Yeah. If you put `async` in front of `def ping_test()` it complains about starting it. `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ping_test' was never awaited`. If I try to await in in the `__init__` function it tells me `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I don't know any more about this, Hope you find the answer though!